# How do I write triangle functions that reads data from a list from a seperate python file?

Tags: python

I am working on a program that has 3 separate python files. My EWGetdata.py file that reads input from a .txt file and puts it into a list of lists. Then I have a EWtriFun.py file that calculates functions of the triangles from the input file. How can I use the data from the list of lists I made in the EWGetdata.py file in the EWtrifun.py file?

This is my EWGetdata.py

```
def getData():
inFile = open("input5.txt", "r")

names = []
vertices = []
my_list = []
for line in inFile:
    line = line.split()

    name = line[0]
    x1 = line[1]
    y1 = line[2]
    x2 = line[3]
    y2 = line[4]
    x3 = line[5]
    y3 = line[6]

    names.append(name)
    vertices.append([[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]])

my_list.append(names)
my_list.append(vertices)
inFile.close()

return(my_list)
getData()
```

This is my Function File so far

```
import EWgetData

local_lst = EWgetData.my_list
```

I get the error AttributeError: module 'EWgetData' has no attribute 'my_list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
You have `my_list` defined within a function and hence its not available outside the fuction to main program.
You can either create a global list and return functions list to the global list.
Or Create a global list and fill data within the function.

Here is former e.g.
In  EWGetdata.py

```
my_list_global = []
my_list_global = getData()
```

Then in EWtriFun.py

```
 import EWGetdata

local_lst = EWgetData.my_list_global
```

**Old**

You can import Getdata.py as module in triFun.py

In Getdata.py

load data from .txt to list of list  to say `data_lst`

In triFun.py
Import getdata file

```
import Getdata
```

You can avail data_lst simply as

```
local_lst = Getdata.data_lst
```

Comment: I added my code to my question, any additional info would be very appreciated.

Comment: See my modified response. You have list within a function in first prog instead of global.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please accept the answer then so that the question doesn't appear as open within SO?